# Vuejs component doesn't propagate updated/deleted data, only created one

Tags: laravel, vue.js, components, vue-component

I have the following structure of components :

School -> MapBox -> StudentMap

School -> Institute -> Student

---

School : is just a wrapper (master component)

Institute : Is a CRUD for the institute from the database and has Student's children

Student : is a CRUD for the student

MapBox : Create a OpenStreetMap

StudentMap : Is there to construct the layer with informations with leaflet

---

I retrieve from the database Institutes which have Students

I know I should need to use Vuex store to have a perfect and clean share of the datas but I had only one week to develop the project and I don't master Vuex still.

The Student component is responsible to edit/delete itself, Institute is responsible to create student, and edit/delete itself. The School, receive the Institutes via laravel json which bind it in the View at the loading.

Whenever an Institute or Student is created/update/deleted, I added event that emits from child to parent to update the data (which is the opposite of what Vue allow but in this usecase I need to let the master component (School) be up-to-date to propagate to the other branch MapBox -> StudentMap.

I have a watcher for the institute / student in the StudentMap and it is triggered when I add new Institute / Student. But when I update / delete, Nothing happen.

I followed of course the good practice to be sure that Vue can catch the modification, like `Vue.delete()` and `Vue.set()` or `arr.splice()` 
[I found thoses informations here](https://fr.vuejs.org/2016/02/06/common-gotchas/)

But Nothing is happening. I don't understand why the Vue propagate the informations when it's created. But not update / delete.

The code is too bit to be put here, but if the description is not clear enough, I created [a gist with it all](https://gist.github.com/dib258/467417e362e5cf6cdecfb839fb53de9e).

Thanks in advance for you help

Comment: You are updating `this.institute.latitude` where `institute` is a prop. That's not good practice.

Comment: Does this work instead of Vue.delete()? `this.database = [...this.database].splice(i, 1)`